# Confused About Warning

Tags: javascript, input, types, warnings

I was trying to code a sudoku board with number fields, and this warning (not error) was returned for each of my number fields:

> The specified value "\u00A0" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

For reference, the code for one of the number files looks like this:

```
<td><input type="number" id="EZT1A1" value=&nbsp max = 9 min = 1></input></td>
```

Can someone explain what the warning means and what I have to do to get rid of it? Thank you!

Comment: What's the actual javascript code you have?

Comment: You've specified that the input should be type `number`, yet are providing it a `value` of a space. You'll need to give it a numeric value (which presumably *should* be specified by the user).

Comment: @tftd The only part that was being affected was the bit of code shown. I worked it out, though; instead of putting value=&nbsp I put value="" and it solved the problem.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I used "" and it made it go away. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you set &nbsp as the value.  You should get rid of the value field all together or replace it with a valid number to get rid of the warning.

Code should read:

```
<td><input type="number" id="EZT1A1" max = 9 min = 1></input></td>
```

Comment: I replaced it with "". Thanks!